# How to use syncfusion report viewer in asp.net webform?

Tags: syncfusion

I am using like

```
    <ej:ReportViewer ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ReportViewer2" runat="server"     ReportPath="~/DMS_MetadataReport.rdlc" ProcessingMode="Local">
    </ej:ReportViewer>
```

But ej is coming as unrecognized server tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below help link to get started with `Syncfusion ASP.Net Reportviewer`.

**Create your first ASP.Net control:** http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/js/index.html#!Documents/createmanually1.htm

**Create your first ReportViewer:**http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/js/index.html#!Documents/createyourfirstreportviewerinaspnet.htm

**Demo:**http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/reportviewer/defaultfunctionalities.aspx

**Class reference:**http://help.syncfusion.com/UG/JS_CR/ejReportViewer.html

From the error you posted it looks like the `Syncfusion.EJ.Web.dll` was not added properly, please refer the above help links to add the dependent `Dll` and `script/CSS` files to use report viewer.

Comment: I haven't registered the DLLs on my .aspx page the above links solves my problem.Thnx